# keep applying transformations to duplicated object

Tags: mirror

is there a way, maybe a plugin, to keep aplying transform changes to duplicated mirrored objects as those happens? i've read about linked duplicates, but seem like those copies everything BUT transformations.

for example, i want to be able to grab the left wing of an aircraft, duplicate and mirror it, then change it's width and immediately see the duplicate change it's widthtoo, then move the original forward and immediatly see the duplicate move forward too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linked duplicates and do transformations in edit mode.
Or use mirror modifier.